# Obtener valor de ratingbar en un Toast

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Les agradezco su ayuda con un problema con el ratingbar, quiero mostrar el valor del ratingbar en un Toast a la hora de pulsar un botón, por ende cada vez que pulse el botón, se deberá mostrar el valor del ratingbar, sin embargo a la hora de pulsar el botón se cierra la aplicación y el debug me sale el siguiente error

> "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'float android.widget.RatingBar.getRating()' on a null object
> reference at
> com.org.notas.asembisencuesta.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:114)
> "

Adjunto el código

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
commentsFra = new ComentariosFragment();
navhost = new HomeFragment();
thanks = new ThanksFragment();
}

public void onClick(View view){
ratingBar = findViewById(R.id.ratingBarOne);
transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
switch (view.getId()){

case R.id.fin_encuesta:
transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, thanks);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, navhost);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
}
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable,7000);
comments = findViewById(R.id.comments_dialog);
comments.setText("");
float rating;
rating = ratingBar.getRating(); //Linea 114
Toast.makeText(this, ":" + rating, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
}
transaction.commit();
}}
```

Y este es el error en el `LogCat`:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.org.notas.asembisencuesta, PID: 7682
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(.java:414)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7146)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7119)
at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:803)
at android.view.View$(View.java:27533)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7386)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(.java:409)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7146)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7119)
at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:803)
at android.view.View$(View.java:27533)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7386)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float android.widget.RatingBar.getRating()' on a null object reference
at com.org.notas.asembisencuesta.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:114)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es el siguiente, en el metodo `onCreate()` te falta indicar una vista para ser inflada mediante el método `setContentView()`. Sin hacer lo anterior, el método `findViewById()` al buscar el ID que le indicas, no lo encuentra ya que no hay ninguna vista donde buscarlo y te devuelve null.

Al intentar usar ratingBar tu aplicación falla ya que ese objeto es null a causa de lo anterior.

Si tu ratingBar reside en un fragmento, deberías buscar la vista tras inflar el fragmento, no antes.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu comentario, el ratingbar si reside en un Fragmento, como podria buscarlo despues de inflar el fragmento? 

Me podrias dar un idea, gracias!!

Comment: Veras, el planteamiento de tu codigo no es correcto, deberías mostrar el Toast desde la clase de tu Fragmento, no desde la Activity. O si quieres hacerlo así, tendras que hacer una comunicación entre los fragmentos y la activity.  Dentro de tu fragmento en `onViewCreated()` puedes buscar tu vista tal que `vista = view.findViewById(R.id.tuVista);`

Si quieres que el fragmento pueda acceder al onClick del boton de la activity deberías hacer una comunicación mediante interfaces o en su defecto LiveData aunque me temo que son conceptos mas avanzados.

Yo personalmente me replantearia la app.